# Sending Attchaments using MailCore2 on ios 8

Tags: ios, mailcore

I am not able to send attachments through MailCore2.
Can I use MailCore for ios 8?.
Can you please provide me the proper approach for it.
I want to send docx,pdf,xls,png and jpeg files in attachments

Comment: Please let us know what you tried here. There's an example about how to send a message on http://libmailcore.com

Answer (score 6):

Loop through all attachments (file paths) and add them to the MessageBuilder:

```
MCOMessageBuilder *msgBuilder = [[MCOMessageBuilder alloc] init];

NSArray *allAttachments = @[@"/var/mobile/etc..", @"/var/mobile/etc2.."];

for (int x = 0; x < allAttachments.count; x++) {
    NSString *attachmentPath = allAttachments[x];
    MCOAttachment *attachment = [MCOAttachment attachmentWithContentsOfFile:attachmentPath];
    [msgBuilder addAttachment:attachment];
}
```

Example of the expected attachment path:

```
"/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/B47D8576-B38E-4864-AC76-8EBC630B6B44/Documents/IMG_0522.JPG"
```

Comment: Definitely works as this is what I am using. Your builder must be correctly coded though and `MCOSMTPSession` must have valid credentials. I updated my answer to make more clear for others.

Comment: why are you storing FileTitle key in the dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

To send an image as attachment in SWIFT just add:

```
    var dataImage: NSData?
    dataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.6)!
    var attachment = MCOAttachment()
    attachment.mimeType =  "image/jpg"
    attachment.filename = "image.jpg"
    attachment.data = dataImage
    builder.addAttachment(attachment)
```

Answer (score 1):

With Swift 4 I had to write this code:

```
if let imageData = self.getImageData(filename: "pic.jpg") {
    var attachment = MCOAttachment()
    attachment.mimeType =  "image/jpg"
    attachment.filename = "image.jpg"
    attachment.data = imageData
    builder.addAttachment(attachment)
}
```

`NSData` is no more usable.